Trying to print from most Windows programs to a CUPS print server on my Raspberry pi
Like the title says, I'm trying to print from any program besides notepad in Windows 11 to a CUPS print server on my raspberry pi. I went through the process of installing updates on my pi, installing CUPS and installing Samba. Although I can print from notepad and print test pages from CUPS URL page and Windows printer page in control panel, I haven't found a way to print a Word Doc. I've tried to research and have had no luck finding anything that looked promising. Any help would be appreciated.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You need only sufficiently recent CUPS (2.3.x +) and avahi-daemon. You also need at least Windows 10 1809.
Share the printer in CUPS, search for it in Windows. It will use Mopria, a driverless mode.
